# How to keep background image on printing

Tags: html, css

I have HTML + CSS page that contains img element with background image in CSS.

In HTML:

```
<img class="symbol>
```

In CSS (Sass):

```
.symbol{
   background-image: url('../images/symbol.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-position: 15px, 15px;
}
```

It is shown correctly in Chrome but on printing (ctrl + P) its automatically remove the background but I need the image background also in the printed page.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I have `media: print` in my css file with no-print. what should i add in order to keep images?

Comment: Sometimes images printing depends on browser configuration.

Comment: Miquel Al. Vicens - Is there a way to override browser settings in css?

Comment: No, this is controlled by user preferences.

Comment: Why doesn't you put the image through source attribute?

Comment: Because I want to improve performance. I want to reduce downloads - download all images in one file. I put all images in one big image (like grid) and every `img` have another `background-position`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161622/discussion-between-miquel-al-vicens-and-haya).

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
@media print {
  .symbol {
    background-image: url('../images/symbol.png');
  }
}
```

to your CSS your background image should show up while trying to print the page. If you still can't see it Chrome provides a few options on print page one of them being `Background graphics`, check it and your image should display.

[image: Chrome Print Page - Background graphics option highlighted]